# Mysql query joining two tables where entry might not exist in one of the tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, like this:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
 +------+------+
 | id   | name |
 +------+------+
 |    1 | joe  |
 |    2 | sue  |
 |    3 | ben  |
 |    2 | dick |
 +------+------+
 4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> select * from table2;
 +------+-----------+
 | id   | something |
 +------+-----------+
 |    1 | whatever  |
 |    1 | whatever2 |
 |    2 | whatever3 |
 +------+-----------+
 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

so, each id can appear 0, 1 or many times in table 2.

How do I do this select query?

I have tried various joins-queries but they exclude all id´s in table1 that does not exist in table2.

Comment: `count() , left join and group by` would do the job.

Comment: Can you give me a more specific select query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LEFT OUTER JOIN enables you to join against a table where there may or may not be a matching record. If no matching record is there then the values from the columns of the other table for that row are NULL.

COUNT(field_name) will count all the non null values of field_name.

Hence you can do a LEFT OUTER JOIN and count the value of one of the fields:-

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, COUNT(table2.id) AS table2count
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.name
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation and a fully working query!